# clone and copy vuex store state moment date

Tags: vue.js, store, vuex

Having a state like:

```
this.$store.state.fromDate
```

I would like to define a variable like this:

```
 var newFrom = this.$store.state.fromDate.subtract(1, 'days');
```

**Without** modifying the value of `this.$store.state.fromDate`

Is it possible?

Comment: its a moment.js date

Comment: mm I am watching this.$store.state.fromDate and everytime I call var newFrom = this.$store.state.fromDate.subtract(1, 'days'); it gets updated with one day less.

Comment: yes but I dont want that to happen, I want to create a new different variable with the value of this.$store.state.fromDate.subtract(1, 'days') without modifying this.$store.state.fromDate, isnt that possible?

Comment: I want to create a different variable from variable this.$store.state.fromDate without modifying the value of  this.$store.state.fromDate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [clone](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/moment-clone/) the moment date:

```
// First, clone the moment date object
var newFrom = this.$store.state.fromDate.clone();
// Then, subtract
newFrom.subtract(1, 'days');
```

This will not subtract to the `this.$store.state.fromDate` but to the `newFrom`

Or, in a single line:

```
var newFrom = this.$store.state.fromDate.clone().subtract(1, 'days');
```

Comment: Ok, the clone is what I was looking for, just var newFrom = this.$store.state.fromDate; wouldnt work, that's what I was trying before asking.

Comment: Glad, it helped!